# How to send object to through axios get method from react to .NET API?

Tags: reactjs, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .NET API
Example:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("GetUser")]
    public ActionResult GetUserDetails(User userReq)
    {
        var response = service.GetUser(userReq);
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

And User class Example:

```
public class User
{
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Age { get; set; }
        public char? Gender { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int? Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling the API in below way through axios in React, Example:

```
axios.get(String(APIUrls.GetUser),
{
    params: {
        ID: null,
        Name: null,
        Age: null,
        Gender: null,
        Email: null,
        Phone: null
    },
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I am able to get response through postman, but when I try from my application its not working.

**Error**:

> Status Code: 415

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"xxxxxxxxxxxx:00000005"}
```

Comment: Try adding [Produces("application/json")] over controller class

Comment: Hi Peter, the API is working fine, I am getting response through postman.

Comment: It surely may work fine, but it may be worth trying, as it does not change the api output, only header of responses.

Comment: I tried it, but still getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[FromQuery]` attribute to specify the source:

```
[HttpGet("GetUser")]

public ActionResult GetUserDetails([FromQuery] User userReq)
{
    //...
}
```